# add dictionary keys to list of categories, and find if there is duplicates in my list, also want to displays the categories and the keys added to it

Tags: c#, list, class, dictionary, duplicates

Here i have both the List and the Dictionary

```
 public static List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
 public static Dictionary<string, ProductInfo> ProductInformation = new Dictionary<string, ProductInfo>();
```

here i let the user to add product to ProductInformation dictionary and check if the product already exist

```
   string articleId;
                    string name;
                    string description;
                    int price;

                    Console.Write("Artikelnummer: ");
                    articleId = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Namn: ");
                    name = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Beskrivning: ");
                    description = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Pris: ");
                    price = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Clear();

                    Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + name + "\n" + "Artikelnummer: " + articleId + "\n" + "Beskrivning: " + description + "\n" + "Pris: " + price + "\n Stämmer detta? (J)a (N)ej");

                    ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

                    if (key.Equals(ConsoleKey.J) && Category.ProductInformation.ContainsKey(articleId))
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("En produkt med samma artikelnummer är redan registerad!");
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (key.Equals(ConsoleKey.N))
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (!pInfo.Equals(pInfo.name) && key.Equals(ConsoleKey.J))
                    {


                        Category.ProductInformation.Add(articleId, new ProductInfo()
                        {
                            name = name,
                            articleNumber = articleId,
                            description = description,
                            price = price
                        });




                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Produkten Registerat!");
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        Console.Clear();

                    }


                    break;
```

here i let the user to add a category to the categories dictionary and also check if the categoey already exist in the dictionary

```
 string catName;

                    Console.WriteLine("Ny Kategori\n");
                    Console.Write("Namn: ");
                    catName = (Console.ReadLine());


                    Console.Clear();

                    Console.WriteLine("Namn: " + catName + "\n Stämmer detta? (J)a (N)ej");
                    key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

                    var categoriee = Category.categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == catName);
                    Category category = new Category(catName);

                    if (key.Equals(ConsoleKey.J) && categoriee != null)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("En Kategori med samma namn är redan registerad!");
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    }
                    else if (key.Equals(ConsoleKey.N))
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Category.categories.Add(category);

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Kategorien Registerat!");
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        Console.Clear();
                    }

                    break;
```

here i let the user to add a product to a category and first check if both the product and the category exists, if they do add product to category.

```
    string categoryName;

                    Console.WriteLine("Artikelnummer på produkten: ");
                    var productArticleNumber = Console.ReadLine();

                    var productExist = Category.ProductInformation.Any(x => x.Key.Contains(productArticleNumber));
                    var productExistInCategory = Category.categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == productArticleNumber);

                    var product = FindProduct(productArticleNumber);

                    if (productExist)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ange Kategorie: ");

                        categoryName = Console.ReadLine();
                        var newCategory = FindCategory(categoryName);



                        if (newCategory != null)
                        {
                            AddProduct(product);
                            Console.WriteLine("Produkten tillagd i kategorien!");
                            Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        }
                        else if (productExistInCategory != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Produkten finns redan i kategorien");
                            Thread.Sleep(2000);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Kategorien finns ej!");
                        }



                    }
                    else if (!productExist)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Produkten hittades ej!");
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }

                    break;
```

Here are the AddProduct method and the findCategory method

```
static Dictionary<string, ProductInfo> ProductDictionary { get; } = new Dictionary<string, ProductInfo>();
    static void AddProduct(ProductInfo product)
    {
        ProductDictionary.Add(product.articleNumber, product);
    }
    static Category? FindCategory(string category)
    => Category.categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == category);
```

Problem 1: The problem is that the program does not let the user to add a product to multiple categories, insted it says that the Key already exist.

Problem 2: i want to display the categories made and the count of its products using this code:

```
 var categorieList = from s in Category.categories select s;
                    foreach (var c in categorieList)
                        Console.Write("\n" + $"Namn: " + c.Name + " " + "[" + ProductDictionary.Count + "]");

                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                    key = ConsoleKey.Escape;

                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.D6:
                case ConsoleKey.NumPad6:

                    break;
```

It displays the categoris and all the products added to the productDictionary, insted i want to just display the catgory and what added to the specifc category.

Comment: You want :Dictionary<string, List<ProductInfo>>

Comment: I get an error on AddProduct method: "cannot convert from 'ProductManager.ProductInfo' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ProductManager.ProductInfo>'"

Comment: You add values to a list like any list.  When you add first item you must use : new List<Productinfo>.  Then later add to list myList.Add(productInfo);

Comment: I cant see how i can implement my code to do that, if you'e kind can you show me a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
   class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();

            Dictionary<string, List<ProductInfo>> ProductInformation = categories
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name, y => y.productInfo)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());
        }

    }
    public class ProductInfo
    {

    }
    public class Category
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ProductInfo productInfo { get; set; }
    }
```